# For loop iterating over growing vector

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, dynamic, vector

My problem is, the for loop below **always** iterates only once.

Before entering the loop, the search_list size is always 1. But the search_list vector may grow inside the loop, and should iterate respectively in case some element is added to the list.

```
   std::vector<int> search_list;
   search_list.clear();
   search_list.push_back(first_elem);

   for(auto &discover : search_list)
   {
       ......
       if(&std::find(face_ids.begin(), face_ids.end(), i))
       {
           search_list.push_back(i);
       }
       ......
   }
```

How can I make this for loop to iterate multiple times based on that growing vector? Even though something is pushed to the search list, it does not iterate more than once. If something is added, it should set the discover to that element and re-enter the loop.

Comment: does your code even compile? btw, search face_ids, generate a temporary vector then insert into search_list in one go.

Comment: It's actually not clear what you want to achieve (to re-start the loop from the begin if an element has been added or merely add that element to the loop, or what?). Adding or removing vector elements inside the range for loop is calling for trouble and most likely undefined.

Comment: I want this loop to keep iterating as long as a new element is pushed to the search_list vector.

Comment: @Caner - A side issue -- `&std::find(face_ids.begin(), face_ids.end(), i)`  Explain what you're trying to do here, especially with the usage of `&`.

Comment: @Caner "I want this loop to keep iterating as long as a new element is pushed". That is not the problem you are trying to solve. that is the problem you created trying to solve your initial problem. People ask you what your initialm problem is because this looks weird, which is not helped by the fact that you hide most of the body of the function and we have no clue where `ì`comes from. There may be a better design approach here, but we need a little bit more context.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I try to check whether the 'find' returns a NULL pointer or valid pointer. Anyway, problem is solved now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the iterator is created when you begin the loop but is not updated then.
You should do the for loop over an index :

```
std::vector<int> search_list;
search_list.clear();
search_list.push_back(first_elem);

for (int ii=0 ; ii < search_list.size() ; ii++) {
       ......
       if(&std::find(face_ids.begin(), face_ids.end(), i))
       {
           search_list.push_back(i);
       }
       ......
}
```

This way, if an element gets added, `search_list.size()` will grow and the loop will go on since it will call it every time.

Be aware that if the `if` statement is always verified, this would yield an infinite loop.

**Edit**: following the suggestion of Félix Cantournet, here is a version with a `while` loop and some control that it cannot go infinite

```
int max_it = 1000;
int ii=0;
...
// i = MAGIC
...
while (&std::find(face_ids.begin(), face_ids.end(), i) && ii < max_it) {
       search_list.push_back(i);
       ......
       // i = NEW MAGIC
       ......
       ii++;
}
```

Comment: Well if you're going to make a potentially infinite loop (which you are) I'd suggest using a `while`with a boolean condition. I think `while(condition)` is more explicit on the "Warning this could be infinite". On a unrelated side note : there must be some way to do what the OP wants to do without a potentially infinite loop.

Comment: @FélixCantournet It depends on what is done in the `....`. If the `i` is unique at each loop, then it is not infinite since the size of `face_ids` is finite (unless it is changed as well but then the code should really be rethought)

Comment: Yes I agree, it is only "potentially" infinite, but still i don't like this design at all. Especially since things are only pushed in `search_list` if  `i is found in face_ids`, I think this should be the condition of the while loop. and leave `search_list.size()` alone.

Comment: To be a little more measured on my last comment : It is hard to choose the correct implementation of this without any knowledge of the generation of the values of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing operations on a container that add or remove elements - or resize - can invalidate all iterators for that container.

A range based for loop assumes the iterators are not invalidated, so would give undefined behaviour if they are.    Essentially, you'll need to resort to a traditional loop.  Break out and restart the outer loop if the container is resized (e.g. place your outer loop in another loop that keeps going as needed).

It will typically involve restructuring your code but, usually, it is safer to avoid resizing a container within a loop that is iterating over the same container.    There are few circumstances in practice where that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you not only change the `end` of the list within the loop (which invalidates the use of a range-based for loop), but possibly also invalidate all `iterators` of the list (which invalidates a `iterator` based for loop.

Therefore, you must resort to something that will not be invalidated. The only thing fits this bill is the index. as in Math's answer.

However, this means that your algorithm is specific to using a `vector` but not, say, a `list` (when you could still use an `iterator`-based for-loop).